# Error : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while doing a insert

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to pick some existing values from Local DB and push into Live DB. The code was working fine and now before deployment., I am facing this issue. Kindly give me solutions

```
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select OPTION_V_DATE, OPTION_V_ER, COMMON_SND, COMMON_SCD, COMMON_OAD, NOTIFY_ID, CREATEDATE, MODIFYDATE, [USER_ID], SMART_EXTRACT, CATEGORY_NUM From REVIEW_NJ_OPTION_5_INFO Order By ID DESC", Cn);
                SqlCommandBuilder sqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapter);
                DataSet selectResults = new DataSet();
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(selectResults); // get dataset                    

                foreach (DataRow row in selectResults.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(@".."))
                    {
                        Con.Open();

                        SqlCommand RD = new SqlCommand("Insert Into NJ_OPTION_5_INFO (OPTION_V_DATE, OPTION_V_ER, COMMON_SND, COMMON_SCD, COMMON_OAD, NOTIFY_ID, CREATEDATE, MODIFYDATE, [USER_ID], SMART_EXTRACT, CATEGORY_NUM)Values('" + row["OPTION_V_DATE"].ToString() + "', '" + row["OPTION_V_ER"].ToString() + "', '" + row["COMMON_SND"].ToString() + "', '" + row["COMMON_SCD"].ToString() + "', '" + row["COMMON_OAD"].ToString() + "', '" + row["NOTIFY_ID"].ToString() + "', '" + row["CREATEDATE"].ToString() + "', '" + row["MODIFYDATE"].ToString() + "', '" + row["USER_ID"].ToString() + "', '" + row["SMART_EXTRACT"].ToString() + "', '" + row["CATEGORY_NUM"].ToString() + "')", Con);
                        RD.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        Con.Close();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I use Datatype Date for column OPTION_V_DATE and DateTime for CREATEDATE and MODIFYDATE.,

Comment: First off you really should be using parameters to avoid potential sql injection.  Second you need to include the data that you are putting into the query, specifically what are the values of `row["OPTION_V_DATE"].ToString()`, `row["CREATEDATE"].ToString()`, and `row["MODIFYDATE"].ToString()`.

Comment: @ juharr  =  row["CREATEDATE"].ToString() = '2015-09-18 20:29:47.000',  row["CREATEDATE"].ToString() = '2015-09-18 20:29:47.000'

Comment: can you post the generated sql string from the sql command that fails? Alternatively you can run a sql profiler to capture the record in question to analyse.

Comment: @Kar : CREATEDATE = '2015-09-18 20:29:47.000' and MODIFYDATE = '2015-09-18 20:29:47.000'

Comment: label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Datepick.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: **The piece of code is right and it is working fine when I change my local system date ie dd before 12. If dd is 13**., It is not getting inserted into live. Any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

`label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: When I changed system date format to yyyy-MM-dd. The things got working well. Thank you all

Comment: 1) You haven't asked us a question, or described *how* your code isn't working.  2) Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.  http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is because the date and time format is different for the two databases. If you are getting the date in DateTime format then send it in DateTime format to the second database i.e. instead of `row["OPTION_V_DATE"].ToString()`

you need to write:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(row["OPTION_V_DATE"])
```

If you are getting the date as a string from the first database then you need to convert the particular string to DateTime format or the formatted DateTime string in which the the second database is configured. Suppose you are getting the date as `dd-MM-yyyy` format in a string and your second database is configured in `yyyy-MM-dd` format then you can do it like this:

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(row["OPTION_V_DATE"].ToString(), "dd'-'MM'-'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 string ss = dt.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd");
```

Now it's your wish which one you need to send - you can either send `dt` or `ss`. Both will work.

Comment: **label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); And Datepick.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");** I pick Date and DateTime like this. Yeah will give a try. Many thanks

Comment: i dont know the format of both the databases... i jst ave an example of yyyy-MM-dd. but u need to chk 1st the datetime format for both the databases

Comment: Bt its better not to convert to string. u need to convert the value for db1 like convert.ToDatetime(row["option_v_date"]) and store the same datetime format in 2nd database

Comment: The problem occurs while I insert into second DB. Convert.ToDateTime(row["OPTION_V_DATE"]) couldn't help. Any other clues. It was working fine yesterday. The problem occurred from today morning

Comment: '" + row["CREATEDATE"].ToString() + "' Any alternate for this., I tried in all mean and I wasted the whole day on this

Comment: then 1st store in a local variable like string ss=row["OPTION_V_DATE"].ToString().split(' ')[0].. then check the date format . after that datetime dd=Datetime.ParseExact(ss,''datetime format of ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); now try to send dd to 2nd database

Comment: '" + row["CREATEDATE"].ToString().Split(' ')[0] + "', '" + row["MODIFYDATE"].ToString().Split(' ')[0] + "' This also didnt help

Comment: **The piece of code is right and it is working fine when I change my local system date ie dd before 12. If dd is 13**., It is not getting inserted into live. Any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

`label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: When I changed system date format to yyyy-MM-dd. The things got working well. Thanks Rajesh.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is quite far off.  When properly parameratized, date format is irrelevant.  Dates should be sent as `DateTime`, not as a string.  Also, `Convert.ToDateTime(row["OPTION_V_DATE"])` does nothing, because the value in the field is *already* a DateTime.  It's just boxed as an object.  You could cast it, but then in this code it's being immediately concatenated back to a string, so `ToString` is being called implicitly.  Thus, there's no advantage.